# jQuery maintain at least one button and maintain values

Tags: jquery, jquery-clone

I would like to remove the button 'OK' but maintain one at least.

```
$(document).on('click', "#client-submit", function(){
    $("#client-div").css('height', $("#client-div").height() + 35);
    $("#client-table").last().clone().appendTo($("#client-div")); 
    $(this).remove(); // problem here
});
```

I do understand the problem..it seems that `last().clone()` is not doing that properly. It seems that instead of getting the last `#client-table` it gets the first one..
You can view the problem [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Mh4wu/)

**Edit**: Forgot to mention, also I would like to maintain the selected value in the previous `select`. How can I achieve that?

Comment: id shouldn't be cloned use class instead.

Comment: @C-link ok that solved my first problem and about the other one?

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is this line:

```
$("#client-table").last().clone().appendTo($("#client-div"));
```

You keep creating "client-table" tables, but you are using ids to get them. jQuery will only ever return first one when you use ids. Hence, the ".last()" is actually getting your first one.

Put a class on "client-table" and use

```
$(".client-table:last")
```

Comment: Yes, that solved my problem about the button. But how do I solve the problem of maintaining the previous selected value?

Answer (score 1):

This should solve it:

```
$("#client-table tr:last").clone().appendTo($("#client-table"));
```

If you want to clear the last input field instead of retaining it, add this after the above statement:

```
$("#client-table").find("input:text:last").val("");
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved all troubles with the help of *stackers*. You can view the solution [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Mh4wu/1/).

1. Changing from `ID` to `Class` solved my problem about the Buttons.
2. Retrieving the value of the select option before clone solved my problem about maintaining the previous content.

Solution:

```
 var i = $(".client-select:last").find(':selected').val();
 $(".client-table").last().find('.client-select').val(i);
```